# Confused on 'using the laws of logic'

Tags: logic

> Use the laws of logic to show the following:
>   $$(a) \quad(p\rightarrow r)\vee (q\rightarrow r) \equiv (p\wedge q)\rightarrow r$$
>   $$(b) \quad [\neg q\wedge (p\rightarrow q)]\rightarrow \neg p\quad \text{is a tautology}$$

I don't understand which laws to use where. I can't seem to change anything that works. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Posting images is acceptable only if there is no other way to ask a question. Otherwise, you should type the question down if you want any answers.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! I edited your post to include the equations directly in your question. Please do not post links to images if it is easily possible to write your question using LaTeX, see this guide: (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: My apologies. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: using $a\rightarrow b\equiv \neg a\vee b$, De Morgan's law and that $\vee$ is associative we get for the RHS of $(a)$: $$(p\wedge q)\rightarrow r \equiv \neg (p\wedge q)\vee r \equiv (\neg p \vee \neg q) \vee r \equiv \neg p \vee \neg q \vee r.$$

Now notice that $$\neg p \vee \neg q \vee r \equiv \neg p \vee r \vee \neg q \vee r$$ and use that $\vee$ is also commutative.

Something similar will work for $(b)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I didn't think of changing the right side. I'm just confused as to how ¬p∨¬q∨r≡¬p∨¬p∨¬q∨r is correct? Where did the extra -p come from? Don't i need two rs not two ps?

Comment: Of course, I meant to add $r$ not $\neg p$,

Comment: Ah, is that because the (¬p∨¬q)∨r is expanded by the r? If so, what law is that?

Comment: No, it is not expaned. It's just that $x\wedge x \equiv x \equiv x\vee x$ (idempotent laws).

Comment: Hmm, i don't understand how ¬p∨¬q∨r≡¬p∨r∨¬q∨r another r is added here. Apart from that i am fine.

Comment: As I said, I'm using the idempotent laws.

Comment: Ah right, that is gyp. I'm also having trouble with this question if thats alright:  q ↔ (¬p ∨ q) ≡  p v q

Comment: https://scontent-lax3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t34.0-12/11912925_10203378529263558_239930463_n.jpg?oh=ea16bc5f68b0ce1d155fe95a61b93bc0&oe=55D3F4B2   < - My attempted solution

Comment: Please do not use the comment section for new questions. Ask another/new question instead. Is everything clear now with the additional $r$?

Comment: Yes, you can turn any variable into that variable and that variable through this: http://puu.sh/jEFMY/ab950b2fbe.png Thanks for your help!